# gcloud SSH connection asks for password instead of passphrase

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, ssh-keys, coreos, gcloud

I've got two VMs set up on Google Cloud Platform. `server1` uses an Ubuntu 16.04 image [g1-small (1 vCPU, 1.7 GB memory)]; and the newly created VM, called `server2`, uses a CoreOS Stable image [f1-micro (1 vCPU, 0.6 GB memory)].

The main problem is I can't connect to `server2` even though I'm using the same SSH Key and user.

I'll be using [this link](https://www.diffchecker.com/tAxGU9av) to compare two output results from `ssh -v`.

---

To make sure I tested this right I erased the files `google_compute_engine`, `google_compute_engine.pub`, `google_compute_known_hosts` and the contents from `known_hosts` in the folder `/Users/userz/.ssh`.

Then executed the command `gcloud init`and then `gcloud compute config-ssh`, which detected that there's no SSH Keys and guided me through the creation of a new one while asking for a **passphrase**, not a **password**. That new SSH Key is the one being used in this test.

If you see the first link for `server1`, ssh ends up asking for the passphrase. But for `server2` ssh ends up asking for a password, where it does not matter what I enter, it just comes as a wrong input every time.

The passwords I tried were: the same passphrase, my login password for the google account, the admin password of the local machine, and every other password I can remember using. And yet wrong input.

**Why is there this difference when I'm using the same method to connect to the VMs? What can I do to solve this, since I do not know nor did setup any password on `server2` (newly created)?**

I may add as a note that connecting through `Cloud Shell` asks for the passphrase and connects easily.

---

`server1` output:

```
ssh -v server1
OpenSSH_7.4p1, LibreSSL 2.5.0
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/userz/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/userz/.ssh/config line 51: Applying options for server1
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to XXX.XXX.XX.XX [XXX.XXX.XX.XX] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/userz/.ssh/google_compute_engine type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/userz/.ssh/google_compute_engine-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to XXX.XXX.XX.XX:22 as 'userz'
debug1: using hostkeyalias: compute.hostkeyaliasX
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
debug1: using hostkeyalias: compute.hostkeyaliasX
debug1: Host 'compute.hostkeyaliasX' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/userz/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/userz/.ssh/google_compute_engine
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 279
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/userz/.ssh/google_compute_engine':
```

`server2` output:

```
ssh -v server2
OpenSSH_7.4p1, LibreSSL 2.5.0
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/userz/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/userz/.ssh/config line 43: Applying options for server2
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to YY.YYY.YYY.YYY [YY.YYY.YYY.YYY] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/userz/.ssh/google_compute_engine type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/userz/.ssh/google_compute_engine-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to YY.YYY.YYY.YYY:22 as 'userz'
debug1: using hostkeyalias: compute.hostkeyaliasY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
debug1: using hostkeyalias: compute.hostkeyaliasY
debug1: Host 'compute.hostkeyaliasY' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/userz/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts:3
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/userz/.ssh/google_compute_engine
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
Password:
```

Comment: Can you use `gcloud compute ssh <instance_name>`?

Comment: @CraigWatson it is the same result, keeps asking for the same "wrong" password

Comment: Maybe `server1:.ssh/authorized-keys` has your client's public key, and `server2:.ssh/authorized-keys` does not?

Comment: @axus Just checked `server2:.ssh/authorized-keys` via `Cloud Shell` (through another user, not `userz`) and in `server2` the user `userz` hasn't been created yet. Shouldn't `gcloud` have taken care of that already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Before doing the following please backup you `~/.ssh/config` file. You may have a bad time if not.

This was solved by deleting the configuration done by `gcloud` with

```
gcloud compute config-ssh --remove
```

After that reinstalling the configuration running the same command as stated in the question:

```
gcloud compute config-ssh
```

This adds an alias for the instance to the user SSH configuration (~/.ssh/config) file and update the project SSH metadata.

Comment: actually i did not need to do this. Just adding the **Service Account User** role (`roles/iam.serviceAccountUser`)  to my UserAccount (or ServiceAccount if i am using ServiceAccount to login) solved the whole issue for me

Answer (score 0):

After going through [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh), I fixed it with:

```sh
export PROB_INSTANCE='your-instance-name'
gcloud compute ssh another-user@$PROB_INSTANCE
```

because the permissions on the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file was not set correctly for the user I was trying to SSH into as previously.

However, YMMV, and this is just what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the **Service Account User** role (`roles/iam.serviceAccountUser`)  to my UserAccount (or to my ServiceAccount if i am using a ServiceAccount to login) solved the whole issue for me.

See **Step 4 Point 2** in https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#configure_users

No need to write/remove/re-write `~/.ssh` values or anything