# gcloud compute ssh asking for password

Tags: ssh, virtual-machines, google-compute-engine, gcp

Here is my situation - I have been SSHing into my VM instances on Google Cloud Platform for years without any issue using the command:

`gcloud compute ssh jackson@myservername`

I just got a new macbook and I transferred everything from my old computer to my new one and now when I run that command it prompts for a password:

`jackson@compute.6803914608257989875's password:`

I have no idea what password this is referring to.

This is only happening on one of my servers. For the other two servers the gcloud compute ssh command works.

After some googling I SSH'd onto the server in the browser from within the GCP console and ran "sudo passwd" and set a new password. I restarted the server - tried SSHing again - it still asked me for a password - I entered the new one I created and it says:

Permission denied, please try again.

I have no idea if that was on the right track at all but just wanted to include what I tried.

I also tried [this solution](https://serverfault.com/questions/875996/gcloud-ssh-connection-asks-for-password-instead-of-passphrase) but it still asks for a password. This is the output:

`jackson@Jackson ~ % gcloud compute config-ssh --remove`

`jackson@Jackson ~ % gcloud compute config-ssh`

`You should now be able to use ssh/scp with your instances.`

`For example, try running:`

`$ ssh myservername.us-east1-b.my-project-name`

`jackson@Jackson ~ % ssh myservername.us-east1-b.my-project-name`

`jackson@compute.6803914608257989875's password:`

`Permission denied, please try again.`

`jackson@compute.6803914608257989875's password:`

I'm at a loss.

Comment: Does "I transferred everything from my old computer to my new one" include your SSH private key in `~/.ssh`? If you manually transferred stuff, that's a hidden directory, and it's what's used by default to connect when SSHing.

Comment: Yes it does. My public and private key are in my .ssh folder. The authorized_keys file on the server has my public key in it and I can still SSH onto my other two servers which use the same keys.